# Not defining Virtual method in derived class as well

Tags: inheritance, virtual, derived

I have the following class hierarchy.

```
class A {
public:
virtual bool foo() const;
};

class B : public A {
     // Redeclare foo as virtual here?
};

class C : public B {
bool foo() const {/*Definition*/ return true;}
};

class D : public B {
bool foo() const {/*Definition*/ return false;}
};
```

So the foo() method the class C and D wants to implement, B doesn't. How can I achieve that? Do I have to re-declare the foo() as virtual in class B?

Note: Ignore minor syntactical error here and there. This is not actual code. My question is only about the concept.

Comment: Did you forget the semicolons after the class declarations in your actual code? That would cause issues.

Comment: ignore syntactical errors. it's not actual code. My question is about the concept.

Answer (score 1):

- If you strictly want a derived class to implement a function then make the function as `pure virtual function` in the base class.
- If you just want random derived class to reimplment a function then simply make the function `virtual` in the base class, which you did in your example.

Now, since function `foo` is `virtual` in base `class A` so a virtual table `vtable` will be create for `class A` and all the classes derived directly or indirectly from `class A`.

Virtual Function entry are stored in `vtable` and they just get replaced in `vtable` if they are reimplemented in the subsequent derived classes.

- So, if `class B` reimplements `foo` then in `vtable` of `class B` the entry will be `B::foo`.
- So, if `class C` reimplements `foo` then in `vtable` of `class C` the entry will be `C::foo`.

So, `class B` is not required to declare function `foo` as `virtual`.

If a function is `virtual` then resolution will happen at run time using the `vtable` of the corresponding class whose object is used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, B does not have to re-implement foo(). It has inherited the function from A. Note that if you create a (stack-allocated) instance of B and call `foo()` on it, then the function is not treated as virtual--A's `foo()` is called.
To use the redefined virtual verson of a function in a derived class (take advantage of polymorphism see), you must call the function via a pointer or reference to an instance of the derived class. Otherwise the static type of the object will be used.

```
B b;

B.foo(); // calls A's foo()

B* b_ptr = &b;
b_ptr->foo(); // calls B's foo()

B& b_ref = b;
b_ref.foo(); // calls B's foo()
```